# Video will not go full width when screen to wide

Tags: javascript, css, video, width

I use [this script](http://jsfiddle.net/mgmilcher/8R7Xx/sho/) to place a video on my homepage.

The problem is when you view it with the browser window on full width and the height on 50%, it doesn't fill the whole window.

```
$(element).each(function(){
    var videoAspectRatio = $(this).data('height')/$(this).data('width'),
        windowAspectRatio = windowHeight/windowWidth;

    if (videoAspectRatio > windowAspectRatio) {
        videoWidth = windowWidth;
        videoHeight = videoWidth * videoAspectRatio;
        $(this).css({'top' : -(videoHeight - windowHeight) / 2 + 'px', 'margin-left' : 0});
    } else {
        videoHeight = windowHeight;
        videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
        $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'});
    }
```

Funny enough it works the other way around (width set to 30% of the screen and full height)

I'm sure it's in the keep dimensions, I juts can't figure out how to change it.

[Live preview here](http://cr.lime-imc.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

```
function scaleVideoContainer() {

var height = $(window).height();
var unitHeight = parseInt(height) + 'px';
$('.homepage-hero-module').css('height',unitHeight);

}

function initBannerVideoSize(element){

$(element).each(function(){
    $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
    $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
});

scaleBannerVideoSize(element);

}

function scaleBannerVideoSize(element){

var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
    windowHeight = $(window).height(),
    videoWidth,
    videoHeight;


$(element).each(function(){
    var videoAspectRatio =      $(this).data('height')/$(this).data('width'),
        windowAspectRatio = windowHeight/windowWidth;

    if (videoAspectRatio > windowAspectRatio) {
      if (windowAspectRatio < 0.564 ){
        videoWidth = windowWidth * 1.15;
        videoHeight = videoWidth * videoAspectRatio * 1.15;
        $(this).css({'top' : -(videoHeight - windowHeight) / 2 + 'px', 'margin-left' : '-20px'});
      }else{
        videoWidth = windowWidth;
        videoHeight = videoWidth * videoAspectRatio;
        $(this).css({'top' : -(videoHeight - windowHeight) / 2 + 'px', 'margin-left' : 0});
      }
    } else {
      if (windowAspectRatio < 0.564 ){
        videoHeight = windowHeight * 1.15;
        videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio * 1.15;
        $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 * 1.1 + 'px'});
      }else{
        videoHeight = windowHeight;
        videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
        $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'});
      }
    }

    $(this).width(videoWidth).height(videoHeight);

    $('.homepage-hero-module .video-container video').addClass('fadeIn animated');


});


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just keep proportions by setting style like this:

```
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
```

Comment: That didn't work and it will also break the video where the height is much bigger than the width ...